# scroll to an ID without using anchor tag or hash

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, anchor

I have an React application that uses hash history, but the problem is, the application currently has anchor tags with ID references so it can scroll to the specific ID. How can I make a scroll animation without using the Anchor tag and scroll to a specified ID?

Comment: You can keep a ref to the element then scroll into view. `<div ref={r => this._toScroll = r}></div>` then `this._toScroll.scrollIntoView()`

Comment: do you mean have a ref in the click element that will scroll to the specific ID or the element it self that needs to be scrolled to?

Comment: You keep the ref to the element you want to scroll to.

Comment: I know you are using react and not angular but would checking out the code in https://github.com/oblador/angular-scroll/ help? I use it to smoothly scroll to elements without needing hash references.

Comment: Okay, if I have an element I want to scroll to such as `<div ref="here">` by clicking on this button `<button>` I would just put the ref inside the button as  well such as `<button ref={r => this._toScroll = r}>`

Comment: You don't need a ref on the button, just an onClick handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use plain JavaScript - **[CodePen Demo](https://codepen.io/dankreiger5/pen/vZPrvZ)**

---

JQuery's [`animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function is much less verbose when it comes to scrolling, but I understand if you don't want to import JQuery into a React project.

Comment: I am not using the JQuery library

Comment: @henhen I posted an update above that uses no JQuery or any other library (other than React, ReactDOM, and React Router of course).